# Routing to home(any component) after authentication from google login in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, google-signin

I have created a log-in component where the user logs in using the google login.
After the authentication, I'm calling my private login method by passing the returned values from google as parameters.

And in login method,if the user has already registered, is navigated to home.

```
public auth2: any;
public googleInit() {
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'my-client id',
    scope: 'profile email'
  });
  this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleSignIn'));
});
}
public attachSignin(element:any) {
this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
  (googleUser:any) => {
    let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    this.login(profile.getEmail(),"", 'S')/*Calling login function*/
   }, 
  (error:any) => {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.googleInit();
}
```

**Below is my login function**

```
login(userId: string, password: string, option: string) {
this.authenticationService.login(userId,password,option)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            if (data.responseStatus) {
                this.isSignBtnDisbld=false;
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            } else {
                alert(data.errorMsg);

            }
        },
        error => {
            alert("Server Error");
        });
}
```

Though the url get routed from sigin to home but the problem is , both the component i.e. (login and home) get merged on the sigle page.And after refreshing,it gets back to normal.

**GUI Attachment**
[Check Image for GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0va7E.png)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually when to components are overlapping, it is due to a form issue. Most commonly, the issue of not declaring the form in html as a named formgroup. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I'm using reactive forms  and bound using formGroup in HTML page.But  keep getting this problem only when logging with google-api. It is working fine when login with my login form or any other social login. And there is no error in console related to this problem.

Comment: hmmm. alright, can you recreate this issue in a stack blitz? also, can you post some screenshots? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Any solution? I am also stuck here